# Uncaught invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, html2canvas, pdfmake

When i do export cloned html to PDF, I'm getting bellow error.

Uncaught invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)

here is my code:

var clonedHTML = $('#ASPxScheduler1').clone();
html2canvas(clonedHTML[0], {
                letterRendering: 1, allowTaint: false, logging: true, useCORS: true,
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                    var docDefinition = {
                        content: [{
                            image: data,
                            width: 1100,
                            height: 450
                        }],
                        pageSize: 'A3',
                        pageOrientation: 'landscape'
                    };
                    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("My-Calendar.pdf");
                }
 });

Comment: ANy luck with this?

Comment: If you have this issue, console.log({data}) to see if your base64 image is truly valid